Aspect Ratio Problem in Converting JSX to PDF
In my React app, I have a fillable PDF form UI that is built manually using jsx and tailwind. I am using html2canvas and jsPDF to convert it to a PDF then upload it to gdrive.
My first problem is, when I test it to google chrome the output that was uploaded to gdrive has an uncentered input data, Even though in UI it was centered through 'flex items-center' via tailwind
Second problem is the browser's zoom in/out affects also the PDF's output. In the site when you fill the form and when you try to zoom out the page, the PDF form content will increase its height and overflow to the page.
So the output that was uploaded to gdrive will look like that also.
my function to convert jsx to pdf is this:
const printDocument = async () => {
    const firstPageCanvas = await html2canvas(firstPageRef.current, { scale: 2 });
    const secondPageCanvas = await html2canvas(secondPageRef.current, { scale: 2 });
    // Create a new jsPDF instance
    const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'letter', true);
    const pageWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    const pageHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

    // Convert the canvas image to a data URL
    const firstPageimgData = firstPageCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const secondPageimgData = secondPageCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    const imgWidth = firstPageCanvas.width;
    const imgHeight = secondPageCanvas.height;

    const ratio = Math.min(pageWidth / imgWidth, pageHeight / imgHeight);
    const imgX = (pageWidth - imgWidth * ratio) / 2;
    const imgY = 30;

    pdf.addImage(firstPageimgData, 'PNG', imgX, imgY, imgWidth * ratio, imgHeight * ratio); // Adjust dimensions as needed
    // Add the image to the PDF
    pdf.addImage(firstPageimgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight); // Adjust dimensions as needed

    // Add a new page
    pdf.addPage();

    // Add another image or content to the new page
    // For demonstration, let's add the same image to the new page
    pdf.addImage(secondPageimgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight); // Adjust dimensions as needed

    // Save the PDF
    const pdfBlob = pdf.output('blob'); // Get the PDF content as a Blob
    return pdfBlob;
};

I already tried to put zoom: 100%; zoom: unset; on the index.css to make the scale constant.
I also put h-[1030px] on the div element of that page so that it wont change the height of the content but still doesnt work.
